# What's the issue with 'PidFile' in section 'Service' (Unknown lvalue 'PidFile' in section 'Service')?

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd service file using instances that works fine for `start` and `status`, but after `stop` a subsequent `status` displays these error messages:

```
Runtime directory is not valid, ignoring assignment: /var/run/iotwatch/%i
Unknown lvalue 'PidFile' in section 'Service'
```

Here are the details: First the service file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/iotwatch@.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=iotwatch I/O performance monitor instance %I
Documentation=man:iotwatch(1)
PartOf=iotwatch.target
#Requisite=
After=nss-user-lookup.target time-sync.target paths.target
#Before=

[Service]
Type=forking
Environment="IOTWATCH_INSTANCE=%i"
RuntimeDirectory=/var/run/iotwatch/%i
WorkingDirectory=/var/run/iotwatch/%i
ExecStart=/usr/lib/iotwatch/iotwatch-service-wrapper %i start
#ExecReload=/usr/...
ExecStop=/usr/lib/iotwatch/iotwatch-service-wrapper %i stop
#SyslogIdentifier=%p-%i
TimeoutStopSec=30
PidFile=/var/run/iotwatch/iotwatch-%i.pid
Restart=always
RestartPreventExitStatus=5 6
StartLimitBurst=1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then the status after start:

```
h02:~ # systemctl start iotwatch@VAR -l
h02:~ # systemctl status iotwatch@VAR -l
● iotwatch@VAR.service - iotwatch I/O performance monitor instance VAR
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iotwatch@.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-04-25 11:40:47 CEST; 6s ago
     Docs: man:iotwatch(1)
  Process: 12907 ExecStart=/usr/lib/iotwatch/iotwatch-service-wrapper %i start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 12920 (iotwatch-VAR)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-iotwatch.slice/iotwatch@VAR.service
           └─12920 ./iotwatch-VAR -l /var/log/iotwatch/VAR/iotwatch-VAR.log -m I -p /var/run/iotwatch/VAR/iotwatch-VAR.pid -d1 -a0.00 -b512 -i4 -sD -t0.5 -TX=0.25:0.50,A=0.025:0.05 -OR -OS:T=F75,S:M=O52,N:3.29/60,Q:C=120,P:nagios.nagios=0664 /dev/sys/var

Apr 25 11:40:47 h02 systemd[1]: Starting iotwatch I/O performance monitor instance VAR...
Apr 25 11:40:47 h02 iotwatch-service-wrapper[12907]: Starting iotwatch VAR
Apr 25 11:40:47 h02 systemd[1]: Started iotwatch I/O performance monitor instance VAR.
h02:~ # ll /var/run/iotwatch/VAR/iotwatch-VAR.pid
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6 Apr 25 11:40 /var/run/iotwatch/VAR/iotwatch-VAR.pid
```

And finally the status after stop:

```
h02:~ # systemctl stop iotwatch@VAR -l
h02:~ # systemctl status iotwatch@VAR -l
● iotwatch@VAR.service - iotwatch I/O performance monitor instance VAR
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iotwatch@.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:iotwatch(1)

Apr 25 11:40:47 h02 systemd[1]: Started iotwatch I/O performance monitor instance VAR.
Apr 25 11:41:24 h02 systemd[1]: Stopping iotwatch I/O performance monitor instance VAR...
Apr 25 11:41:24 h02 iotwatch-service-wrapper[12962]: Stopping iotwatch VAR
Apr 25 11:41:27 h02 systemd[1]: Stopped iotwatch I/O performance monitor instance VAR.
Apr 25 11:41:27 h02 systemd[1]: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/iotwatch@.service:12] Runtime directory is not valid, ignoring assignment: /var/run/iotwatch/%i
Apr 25 11:41:27 h02 systemd[1]: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/iotwatch@.service:19] Unknown lvalue 'PidFile' in section 'Service'
Apr 25 11:41:27 h02 systemd[1]: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/iotwatch@.service:12] Runtime directory is not valid, ignoring assignment: /var/run/iotwatch/%i
Apr 25 11:41:27 h02 systemd[1]: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/iotwatch@.service:19] Unknown lvalue 'PidFile' in section 'Service'
Apr 25 11:41:32 h02 systemd[1]: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/iotwatch@.service:12] Runtime directory is not valid, ignoring assignment: /var/run/iotwatch/%i
Apr 25 11:41:32 h02 systemd[1]: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/iotwatch@.service:19] Unknown lvalue 'PidFile' in section 'Service'
```

How can I fix the service file to avoid those messages?

Comment: Should I post this question on a different site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting is called "PIDFile=", not "PidFile=", see documentation.

RuntimeDirectory= takes a relative path, see documentation.

Please always have a look at the documentation first. This things are well documented.

Comment: But why is the problem reported only if the service is stopped (see outputs in question)? It seems the syntax checking is done only for `stop`.

Comment: After fixing the two problems with `PIDFile` and `RuntimeDirectory`, I still get a "Runtime directory is not valid, ignoring assignment: iotwatch/%i".

Comment: I found it: `iotwatch/%i` is invalid because of the slash. That's the biggest problem with `systemd`: It does not only provide mechanisms, but it enforces rules that the developer likes, but almost nobody else.

Comment: If you want help, it's best to be friendly and not post stuff about how mean the developers are. That's really not helpful. In particular as you are very wrong. We added support for paths that include a "/" in systemd 235. Please consider updating.